# First time trying to use ActiveRecord "where", failing

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my app, `puts self.ideas.inspect` outputs:

```
[#<Idea id: 1, title: "Ad et ut nesciunt ut.", 
note: ["Ratione et aut harum.", "Dicta nostrum sit officiis voluptates molestiae veritatis ut."], 
status: "claimed", 
created_at: "2012-12-27 19:03:11", updated_at: "2012-12-27 19:03:11", user_id: 1>, 
#<Idea id: 2, title: "Asperiores dolores modi et.", 
note: ["Reprehenderit harum consequuntur repellendus qui.", "Labore eum minus voluptas quidem aliquid est occaecati."], 
status: "claimed", 
created_at: "2012-12-27 19:03:11", updated_at: "2012-12-27 19:03:11", user_id: 1>, 
#<Idea id: 3, title: "Labore nam deserunt quibusdam.", 
note: ["Sequi saepe itaque.", "Numquam distinctio vel hic et qui."], 
status: "claimed", 
created_at: "2012-12-27 19:03:11", updated_at: "2012-12-27 19:03:11", user_id: 1>]
```

Yet in the next line, `claimed_count = self.ideas.where(status: "claimed").size` returns 0. My query syntax is obviously wrong, but I've been poring over [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions) and I still can't figure it out!

Must be something very basic... Anyone?

**Edit:** I got this collection of ideas using the following test:

```
it "can't claim an idea if he already has 3 ideas with claimed status" do
  james.claim(si_title0)
  james.claim(si_title1)
  james.claim(si_title2)
  james.claim(si_title3)
  james.ideas.size.should eq 3
end
```

I'm sorry for the ugly test... I was going to try to figure out interpolation for refactoring it after I get it passing. The `inspect` dump above is from the third or fourth iteration of the loop.

**Edit 2:** This is what `claim` does:

```
  def claim(idea)
    puts self.ideas.inspect
    #claimed_count = self.ideas.where(status: "claimed").count
    claimed_count = self.ideas.count(conditions: "status='claimed'")
    puts "claimed_count is #{claimed_count.inspect}"
    if idea.status == "available" && claimed_count < 3
      self.ideas<<idea
      idea.status = "claimed"
    end
  end
```

So... does it not save to the database? If so, how should I fix that?

Comment: How did you get this collection of `ideas`?  Was it already saved to the database in this state as you are presenting it?

Comment: Does `.count` work instead of `.size` ?

Comment: @PinnyM - edited to add invoking code above.

Comment: @Zabba - I'm afraid not... No difference, exactly the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that `claim()` is not saving the "claimed" `idea` status to the database.  You need to either change this behavior (if that's what you really need), or search on the `ideas` Enumerable itself instead of querying the database via `where`.  You can use `select` for this:

```
james.ideas.select{|idea| idea.status == "claimed"}.size
```

And you can add a helper method to `Idea` to make querying simpler:

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  def claimed?
    status == "claimed"
  end
end

james.ideas.select(&:claimed?).size
```

**UPDATE**

Your code will not save the status as it is because nothing is called to save the `idea` object after you change the `status` attribute.  You can fix this by reversing the order of your calls:

```
if idea.status == "available" && claimed_count < 3
  idea.status = "claimed"
  self.ideas<<idea
end
```

The `<<` 'shovel' operator will save the idea since you are adding it to an association collection of a persisted object.

Comment: I think maybe you're right and `claim` doesn't save... I thought it does - it's definitely supposed to. I edited the question to include the full `claim` body -- could you take a look?

Comment: Nope it won't save it that way - see my suggestion on how to fix.

Comment: Wow! That absolutely works! Answer accepted, but would you mind explaining why that works? What happens when I do `self.ideas<<idea`?

Comment: See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).  It remarks that the '<<' operator will immediately fire a save or update on the object being added.  However, this can only happen if the parent has already been saved, otherwise the new object has no foreign id to belong_to.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is torn down at the end of each test - once the test concludes, the data inserted will be rolled back; it should not be persisting between tests!

How and where are you using your `where`, and what does your model (specifically the `ideas` association) look like?